# Codeigniter - How to access the result_array()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a method in my controller as follows:

```
function surcharge_load_data(){
    $data = $this->Surcharge_model->surcharge_load_data();   
    foreach($data->result_array() as $r) {
           echo $r->surcharge_id;
      }
 }
```

The Surcharge_model method returns a result array.  This is my method in the model:

```
function surcharge_load_data(){
    $this->db->order_by('surcharge_id', 'DESC');
    $query = $this->db->get('surcharges');
    return $query->result_array();
}
```

The data returned from the above method looks like this:

```
[{"surcharge_id":"37","surcharge_curr":"EUR","surcharge_name":"MNM","surcharge_unit_id":"3","surcharge_value":"43","surcharge_category_id":"3","created_timestamp":"2019-06-03 06:18:18","updated_timestamp":"2019-09-01 08:19:18"},

{"surcharge_id":"36","surcharge_curr":"EUR","surcharge_name":"TOY","surcharge_unit_id":"3","surcharge_value":"433","surcharge_category_id":"3","created_timestamp":"2019-07-09 09:21:21","updated_timestamp":"2019-09-10 09:21:21"}]
```

A few questions as follows:

(1) The entire data is encapsulated in [].  Does that mean it has returned one large object with array of arrays?

(2) Why do I get an error, Call to a member function result_array() on array?  I thought $data is a result array.  How can I access it please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, no need to use `result_array()` here

```
function surcharge_load_data(){
    $data = $this->Surcharge_model->surcharge_load_data();   
    foreach($data as $r) {//changes
           echo $r['surcharge_id'];
      }
 }
```

> HERE, you are using `result_array()` so you need to use each object like `$r['surcharge_id']` if you use `result()` then you need to use `$r->surcharge_id`

Comment: Thanks.  Tried that previously but I get an error, Trying to get property of non-object on line, echo $r->surcharge_id;

Answer (score 2):

From your controller you can't retrieve the `result_array` method because this only exists within your Model.

So, in your controller you can read the answer from your model like:

```
function surcharge_load_data(){
    $data = $this->Surcharge_model->surcharge_load_data();   
    foreach($data as $r) { 
           //just here you can retrieve your data
           ...
      }
 }
```

Where `$data` is the result from the model (before returned as `$query->result_array()`) which your are recieving in your controller